# Changing default path of app logs in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, logging

I was wondering, if there's any way of changing the logs directory of my app, without changing paths.php (which is part of cake, not my app, in cake/config).

I tried "App::build(array('logs' => array('c:'.DS.'logs')))", in bootstrap, but I guess it just doesn't work that way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old but CakePHP 2.x allows for a custom path now for logs.

From [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html):

> You can configure additional/alternate FileLog locations using
>   CakeLog::config(). FileLog accepts a path which allows for custom
>   paths to be used:

```
<?php
CakeLog::config('custom_path', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'path' => '/path/to/custom/place/'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, there's no way to tell Cake you want to store its logs elsewhere, other than modifying `cake/config/paths.php`, and yeah, making deployment-specific changes to a `/cake` file isn't a great idea.

Unless you have a specific need for actually *storing* the log files outside the Cake directory structure, you could create a symbolic link between Cake's `/app/tmp/logs` and your desired logs directory:

- Windows: `C:\logs> mklink /D my_app C:\path\to\your\app\tmp\logs`
- Linux/Unix/MacOS: `/var/logs/or/whatever $ ln -s /path/to/your/app/tmp/logs my_app`